# Can't get $_POST values (php, html)

Tags: php, forms, post, include, scope

I can't get the $_POST['name'] values sent from an html form on my php file. I've seen lots of similar questions but nothing helped. I have lot's of includes so I believe it's a scope issue, but I can't figure it out.

index.php

```
print_r($_POST); //Returns nothing, tried other ways too

//lot's of variables being defined

include 'sql_data_handlers.php';
//instantiating some things
```

sql_data_handlers.php

```
//some functions retrieving data from sql db and finally:
include($DOCUMENT_ROOT . "page.html");
```

page.html

```
//html stuff
<?php
//Some conditions
include($DOCUMENT_ROOT . "comment_form.html");
?>
```

comment_form.html

```
<form action="index.php" name="comment_form" id="comment_form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Anonymous" required><br>
    //lot's of inputs
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I used to have `action="send_comment.php"` but I realized it could be turned into a function so I ctrl+c and adapted `send_comments.php` to a function on `sql_data_handlers.php`. The problem is, now I can't get the `$_POST` values on `index.php` to use in the function on `sql_data_handlers.php` (which is included in `index.php`).

I would use `action="my_php_function_from_data_handlers.php($args)"` if it was possible, but I guess it isn't. btw, I already tried `action=""`. This may seem pretty messy but this way I only need one .html for the site layout, pages are on the sql and the .php files do all the job.

Complete source of all files (pretty big, still working on it):
http://pastebin.com/2nRuCpNx

Comment: did you tried to change the extension of your .html files to .php?

Comment: If you post the form and inspect the request with Firebug/F12/Developer Tools, can you see the POST data?

Comment: Kaii is right, inside html file (comment_form.html) you use php code and that will not work.

Comment: Just changed the name of all .html files to .php, updated the includes but still can't get the $_POST values.

Comment: Kaivosukeltaja Dev tools says "Method: POST Status: Found 431B"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any kind of redirects, since you're using index.php to save data, you're probably reloading the page to show the updated comments. And if you're reloading, there'll be no data on $_POST to be printed by print_r().

Comment: That was it, the .php script was refreshing the page once the submit button was clicked so the $_POST variables were lost -- the array was in fact being generated, I just overlooked it. Thanks.

Comment: You saved my day. I had a rewrite rule that was sending all `http://my_domain.com` to `http://www.my_domain.com` and it lost the _POST data in the process. Maybe my comment helps someone who uses rewrite rules in .htaccess files.

Comment: @DudeOnRock Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the value of the input name attribute to something different from "name". Some configurations have issues with that, especially wordpress.

for example:

```
<input type="text" name="user_name" value="Anonymous" required>
```

Comment: There are other inputs with other names, none of them are being send.

Comment: @user117893 I understood, and still I know that it can cause trouble. There's no harm in trying, right?

Answer (score 0):

would you mind to change your

**.html** filename to **.php** filename

your codes runs in my local server because sometimes the difference lies in how your web server is configured.

when running in an web server it is best to use .php in your files

Comment: I already did, the result is the same - I can't get $_POST values.

Comment: Yes. The $_POST requests were sent to send_comments.php before, I as I said. The prolem is index.php isn't getting them for some reason.

Comment: thats weird.. i try it and get results.. try to use different action instead of index.php